# Bluetooth power consumption on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, consumption

This is my first question and I think it will be hard to answer :)

My question is

Does anyone know how much consumed in mAh Bluetooth on Android?

I know it depends on the device, but I need a approximate value without much detail

Thank you very much to all

Comment: More than is consumed without bluetooth in use =). For serious though, this is too broad and is nearly unanswerable. There are various battery statistic applications on the market. Grab some of them and and test on a device. However be aware that there are so many variables that go into how much power is being consumed at a given time that you are going to need a very large sample size to get much meaningful info.

Comment: In this link

http://knol.google.com/k/android-programando-para-la-vida-de-la-batería#

Shows the approximate energy consumption of the main funcionalies the device. I know these values ​​can be uncertain and not very detailed but only need an approximate value to begin to study and have a starting value.

To get an idea ...

Answer (score 1):

You can check the power_profile.xml file on your device. The value inside is set by the manufacture as reference. You can use [Power Profile Application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.anndroid.powerprofile&hl=en_GB) in Google Play to see the value.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this research paper. It probably won't tell you in mAh but you might be able to approximate it.  I assume they are uploading and downloading until the battery reaches ~0. So if they give the model of the phone and it's batter capacity you can figure that out.

https://bib.irb.hr/datoteka/575153.Energy_Consumption_in_Android_Phones_when_using_Wireless_Communication_Technologies.pdf

Comment: In the paper they only measure battery consumption when the data is downloaded/uploaded at maximum speed possible. That's only one particular use case. There are many cases when data rate is much lower. Not very useful...

Comment: I would argue that it is useful because it will tell you the amount of energy consumed at the highest rate.  This could be used for a baseline minimum capacity. Do another study on idle and you now have a range.  It will never be exact unless you test the operating conditions you intend on operating under.